# Not Select Bottom Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c72cd/1) , 
 
 Why it not counting until last row? 
 I want output that count until last row. 
 It count the interval of **STATUS = 0**

```
    CREATE TABLE [Alerts]
(
  [Timestamp] datetime,
  [Status] int
)

INSERT INTO [Alerts] ([Timestamp], [Status])
  VALUES
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:00', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:05', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:10', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:15', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:20', 0),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:25', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:30', 1),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:32', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:35', 2),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:40', 0),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:45', 0),
    ('2013-1-1 00:00:50', 0)
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT
  MIN ([main].[Start]) AS [STOP_Begin],
  [main].[End] AS [STOP_End],
  DATEDIFF(s, MIN([main].[Start]), [main].[End]) AS [Interval_Second]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [sub].[Start],
    MIN([sub].[End]) AS [End]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [start].[Timestamp] AS [Start],
      [start].[Status] AS [StartingStatus],
      [end].[Timestamp] AS [End],
      [end].[Status] AS [EndingStatus]
    FROM [Alerts] [start],  [Alerts] [end]
    WHERE [start].[Status] = 0
      AND [start].[Timestamp] < [end].[Timestamp]
      AND [start].[Status] <> [end].[Status]
  ) AS [sub]
  GROUP BY
    [sub].[Start],
    [sub].[StartingStatus]
) AS [main]
GROUP BY
  [main].[End]
```

It give output: 
[image: OUTPUT]
I want output that count until last row, if **0** is the last row it gives me **Interval=NULL** , 
My problem it doesn't count until last row where **0** there

My desired result:

```
 ---------STOP_BEGIN-----         --------STOP_END--------- ----INTERVAL_SECOND-----<br />
January, 01 2013 00:00:20+0000  January, 01 2013 00:00:25+0000      5
January, 01 2013 00:00:40+0000           NULL                       NULL
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: the last row where the status 0, it not give result the count of its interval, if the last row is 0  i want the interval **output = NULL**

Comment: @KenWhite , please see again

Comment: +1. Much, much better. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your query (I have added it to the SQL Fiddle to the bottom of yours)

```
SELECT
  MIN ([main].[Start]) AS [STOP_Begin],
  [main].[End] AS [STOP_End],
  DATEDIFF(s, MIN([main].[Start]), [main].[End]) AS [Interval_Second]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [starts].[Start],
    MIN([ends].[Timestamp]) AS [End]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [Timestamp] AS [Start]
    FROM [Alerts]
    WHERE [Status] = 0
  ) AS [starts] LEFT JOIN [Alerts] AS [ends]
  ON  [starts].[Start] < [ends].[Timestamp]
  AND [ends].[Status] <> 0
  GROUP BY
    [starts].[Start]
) AS [main]
GROUP BY
  [main].[End]
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: and what do you want? Can you please provide the desired result?

Comment: please see my post again, if i change it to **MAX** it gives me wrong result because what i want to have second row where it counts **STATUS = 0 from 00:00:40** and gives me **INTERVAL = NULL** because it is the last **STATUS = 0**

Comment: can you post the desired output the way you showed us "It give output"

Comment: please see my post again, i've changed it

Comment: not sure if you are getting notifications about the answer updates. Here you go, updated answer